# android: how to consume web service which is running locally

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, localhost

So, I have created a RESTful web service with ASP.net Web API 2.0
and I am running it locally. I checked, it working well in RestClients of browsers. Now I want to consume it inside my Android emulator. I want to comsume from Android's default browser or from within my application.

So, is it possible to do so ? I searched a lot but didn't find what I am looking for. (It may have happened that I didn't enter proper search terms, as I am confused what to write) Please help me. Thanks.

**Edit:**

I also tried running this way: I ran the web api prject and checked for the following service url as below:

```
http://localhost:9067/api/equipment
```

In emulator's browser, I tried (guess):

```
http://10.0.2.2/api/equipment
```

This is the config I am getting when I checked using ipconfig:

```
IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.5
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

When we consume a web service using Internet, we use the external ip and port of the server. But, when we need to do same locally we need to use the internal ip of your server. Find internal ip from Windows command using ipconfig or linux by command ifconfig

Comment: Sorry. This didn't worked for me. It says, 400 - bad request : The host name is invalid.